# Dropdown menu not closing when another dropdown is open(active)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown menu where the .dropdown-content shows up when is clicked, and disappears if the user clicks any other dropdown in the bar. The problem is I have multiple dropdown classI think I just need help revising my existing javascript.
I would like that the sidebar(nav) only display the dropdown menu that is current active. On my code when you open a dropdown it still open until the user click  the dropdown arrow again to close that specific one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict"; // Start of use strict

      //Sidebar menu
      $('.show-sidebar').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('collapse-sidebar');
        $('#layout-admin').toggleClass('collapse-sidebar');
      });
      $('.has-sub').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub2').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub2').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav2').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub3').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub3').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav3').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub4').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub4').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav4').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub5').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub5').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav5').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub6').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub6').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav6').slideToggle("slow");
      });
      $('.has-sub7').on('click', function() {
        $('.has-sub7').toggleClass('open-dropdown');
        $('.sub-nav7').slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Segoe WP Light", "Segoe UI", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Segoe WP Light", "Segoe UI", "Arial", sans-serif;
}


/*============================
Header
============================*/

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a .icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  background: #ffffff1a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

ul li a .icon span {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #b0b3b8;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

span.field-requried {
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #333);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub2::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub3::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub4::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub5::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub6::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub7::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub8::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub2.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub3.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub4.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub5.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub6.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub7.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub8.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:hover,
#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar .sidebar-header img {
  width: 40px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#layout-admin {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}

#layout-admin .header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(232, 2, 21);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left {
  font-size: 0;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right a {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}

#username {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right .setting {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left button.show-sidebar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  /*-webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px white;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .title span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#layout-admin .content-admin {
  padding: 20px;
}

#layout-admin .content-admin .title-content {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#layout-admin.collapse-sidebar {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
}

.sub-nav,
.sub-nav2,
.sub-nav3,
.sub-nav4,
.sub-nav5,
.sub-nav6,
.sub-nav7,
.sub-nav8 {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-nav li,
.sub-nav2 li,
.sub-nav3 li,
.sub-nav4 li,
.sub-nav5 li,
.sub-nav6 li,
.sub-nav7 li,
.sub-nav8 li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 30px;
}

#sidebarCollapse-mobile {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header img {
    width: 40px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar .sidebar-header img {
    width: 100px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 8px 25px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  *#layout-admin {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
  }
  #layout-admin.collapse-sidebar {
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }
  #layout-admin .header .header-left .title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #layout-admin .header .header-right a {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  #username {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar #sidebarCollapse-mobile {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <!--------------------- Sidebar header  ---------------------------->
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <a href="#"><img src="/common/images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse-mobile" class="show-sidebar">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <!--------------------- Sidebar menu  ---------------------------->
    <ul class="list-unstyled nav-links">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-pendingorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub open-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-box-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Pending Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-collectorders" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-crosshairs"></span> Collect orders</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-addneworder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-box-open"></span> Partial collect</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-warehousecollect" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-warehouse"></span> Warehouse collect</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-outofstock" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-surprise"></span> Out of Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-ordered" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-thumbtack "></span> Ordered</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-rts" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-recycle"></span> RTS</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-awaitinglist" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-pause-circle"></span> Awaiting List</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="li-manageorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub3 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Manage Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav3" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-addneworder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-eye"></span> View Order</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-warehousecollect" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span> Create Order</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="li-packorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub5 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-tape" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Pack Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav5" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tape"></span> Pack Orders</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="li-manageinventory">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub7 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Manage Inventory</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav7" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-sliders-h"></span> Adjust Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-truck-loading"></span> Receive Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-dolly"></span> Ship Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></span> Locations</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="li-orderdownload">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Download Orders</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-tracking">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub2 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Tracking</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav2" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-markorderassent" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-truck"></span> Mark Order as Sent</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-downloatrackings" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-arrow-down"></span> Download Trackings</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-uploadtrackings" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-arrow-up"></span> Upload Trackings</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="labels">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub4 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-tags"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Labels</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav4" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-createlabels" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tag"></span> Create Labels</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-morelabels" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tags"></span> More Labels (template)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="refunds">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Refunds</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="manageadm">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub6 open-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-users-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Admin</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav6" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-usermanagement" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user-cog"></span> User Management</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packermanagement" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-toolbox"></span> Packer Management</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is have a lot of reusable code Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict"; // Start of use strict
  
        $('.show-sidebar').on('click', function() {
          $('#sidebar').toggleClass('collapse-sidebar');
          $('#layout-admin').toggleClass('collapse-sidebar');
        });
        $('li a.has-sub').on('click', function() {
          // For toggle its own li
          $(this).toggleClass('open-dropdown');
          $(this).parent().find('.sub-nav').slideToggle("slow");

          // For other li
          $(this).parent().siblings().children('a.has-sub').removeClass('open-dropdown');
          $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul.sub-nav').slideUp("slow");
        });
  });
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Segoe WP Light", "Segoe UI", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Segoe WP Light", "Segoe UI", "Arial", sans-serif;
}


/*============================
Header
============================*/

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a .icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  background: #ffffff1a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

ul li a .icon span {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #b0b3b8;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

span.field-requried {
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #333);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub2::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub3::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub4::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub5::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub6::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub7::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub8::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub2.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub3.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub4.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub5.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub6.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub7.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a.has-sub8.open-dropdown:after {
  content: "\f107";
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:hover,
#sidebar ul.list-unstyled li.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar .sidebar-header img {
  width: 40px;
}

#sidebar ul.list-unstyled {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#layout-admin {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}

#layout-admin .header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(232, 2, 21);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left {
  font-size: 0;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right a {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}

#username {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-right .setting {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left button.show-sidebar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  /*-webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px white;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

#layout-admin .header .header-left .title span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#layout-admin .content-admin {
  padding: 20px;
}

#layout-admin .content-admin .title-content {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#layout-admin.collapse-sidebar {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
}

.sub-nav,
.sub-nav2,
.sub-nav3,
.sub-nav4,
.sub-nav5,
.sub-nav6,
.sub-nav7,
.sub-nav8 {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-nav li,
.sub-nav2 li,
.sub-nav3 li,
.sub-nav4 li,
.sub-nav5 li,
.sub-nav6 li,
.sub-nav7 li,
.sub-nav8 li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 30px;
}

#sidebarCollapse-mobile {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header img {
    width: 40px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar .sidebar-header img {
    width: 100px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 8px 25px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a i {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li:first-child a i {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar ul.list-unstyled li a span.sidebar-menu-text {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  *#layout-admin {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
  }
  #layout-admin.collapse-sidebar {
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }
  #layout-admin .header .header-left .title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #layout-admin .header .header-right a {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  #username {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #sidebar.collapse-sidebar #sidebarCollapse-mobile {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <!--------------------- Sidebar header  ---------------------------->
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <a href="#"><img src="/common/images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse-mobile" class="show-sidebar">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <!--------------------- Sidebar menu  ---------------------------->
    <ul class="list-unstyled nav-links">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-pendingorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fas fa-box-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Pending Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-collectorders" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-crosshairs"></span> Collect orders</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-addneworder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-box-open"></span> Partial collect</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-warehousecollect" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-warehouse"></span> Warehouse collect</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-outofstock" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-surprise"></span> Out of Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-ordered" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-thumbtack "></span> Ordered</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-rts" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-recycle"></span> RTS</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-awaitinglist" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-pause-circle"></span> Awaiting List</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="li-manageorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Manage Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-addneworder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-eye"></span> View Order</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-warehousecollect" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span> Create Order</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="li-packorders">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fa fa-tape" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Pack Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tape"></span> Pack Orders</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="li-manageinventory">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Manage Inventory</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-sliders-h"></span> Adjust Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-truck-loading"></span> Receive Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-dolly"></span> Ship Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packorder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></span> Locations</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="li-orderdownload">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Download Orders</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="li-tracking">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Tracking</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-markorderassent" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-truck"></span> Mark Order as Sent</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-downloatrackings" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-arrow-down"></span> Download Trackings</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-uploadtrackings" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-arrow-up"></span> Upload Trackings</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="labels">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fas fa-tags"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Labels</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-createlabels" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tag"></span> Create Labels</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-morelabels" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-tags"></span> More Labels (template)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="refunds">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Refunds</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="manageadm">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-sub">
          <i class="fas fa-users-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class='sidebar-menu-text'>Admin</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
          <li id="li-usermanagement" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user-cog"></span> User Management</a>
          </li>
          <li id="li-packermanagement" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <a style="height: 30px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 15px;" href="#"><span class="fas fa-toolbox"></span> Packer Management</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, I am going to work on that part of the code to remove the unnecessary.